# Upating shared preferences on reciever side in real time?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

this is my first android app i am trying to update the sharedpreferences on reciever side in realtime below the code is for mainactivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        disp =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String host = sharedPreferences.getString(hostip,"");

        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(),"tcp://"+host,clientId);

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connection failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

settings.java which is the sender side

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String hostip = "hostipkey" ;
    public static final String topic = "topickey" ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipadd);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.api);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);



        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String host  = editText1.getText().toString();
                String api  = editText2.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(hostip, host);
                editor.putString(topic, api);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(settings.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

     }
```

The above code works good but the issue i am facing is that my data in shared preference does not update on the reciever side in realtime. In order to get the data i had to restart the app again so my new values in main activity get updated. any help regarding this is much appreciated

Regards
saif

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the value in `onResume` in MainActivity it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are a life saver sir

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Muthukishnan is right because `onResume()` will be called after creation and restarting, `onCreate()` only when Activity is created.

See: [Application Lifecircle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOshB.png)